# Different permalink structure for blog posts than pages in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'd like to have a different permalink structure for posts than for pages on a Wordpress website.

For example, a blog post name "This is a nice blog post" would get the permalink :
/blog/this-is-a-nice-blog-post

where as a page called "Services Offered" would get the permalink :
/services-offered

I know I should use the %postname% in the permalink structure, but how to add the prefix /blog/ to only those blog posts ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here it's the answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22890/how-would-i-create-a-different-permalink-structure-for-pages-and-posts

Comment: This option is the best option: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15619416/2349527 :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Under the permalink settings, you need to use a custom format. To do this, you'll need to take a look at the structure tags available for use. Those can be found here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

To do exactly what you're wanting, you'd want to use a format like this:

/%category%/%postname%/

Pages have no category, so the tag for categories gets ignored and only the post name tag gets used.

I just found this question looking for the same answer. Hope this isn't too late and helps you out.

Comment: This will not work if you have multiple blog categories, instead it will use the category name... better to use /blog/%postname%/ - this will only affect posts (and not pages)