# Wordpress Custom Permalink for Just Posts

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

My Wordpress install has three post types: pages, posts, and portfolio. The current structure is as follows:

- page: `example.com/page-name`,
- post listing page: `example.com/blog`,
- **individual post**: `example.com/post-name`,
- portfolio listing page: `example.com/portfolio`,
- individual portfolio post: `example.com/portfolio/portfolio-name`.

The thing I'd like to change is the individual post permalink, but nothing else. I'd like it to become example.com/blog/post-name.

I can't find documentation that shows how to make this change without affecting the other types.

**EDIT** : 
My current permalink structure is set up to be `/%postname%/`, and under Reading Settings, my posts page is set to Blog.

```
register_post_type('portfolio', array(  
'label' => 'Portfolio Items',
'description' => '',
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'hierarchical' => true,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio'),
'with_front' => false,
'query_var' => false,
'has_archive' => true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes'),
'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag'),
'labels' => array (
    'name' => 'Portfolio Items',
    'singular_name' => 'Portfolio Item',
    'menu_name' => 'Portfolio Items',
    'add_new' => 'Add Portfolio Item',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Portfolio Item',
    'edit' => 'Edit',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Portfolio Item',
    'new_item' => 'New Portfolio Item',
    'view' => 'View Portfolio Item',
    'view_item' => 'View Portfolio Item',
    'search_items' => 'Search Portfolio Items',
    'not_found' => 'No Portfolio Items Found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Portfolio Items Found in Trash',
    'parent' => 'Parent Portfolio Item',
)
));
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You simply have to set `/blog/%postname%/` as your permalinks structure, this will not change your pages permalinks.

And to keep your portfolio permalinks, you should set [`with_front`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) to `false` when you register this post type.

> `'with_front' => bool` Should the permastruct be prepended with the
>   front base. (example: if your permalink structure is `/blog/`, then your
>   links will be: `false->/news/`, `true->/blog/news/`). Defaults to true

EDIT 1 : You should probably [flush Wordpress rewrite rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) after that.

EDIT 2 : `with_front` param is a `rewrite` param :

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => false),
```

Comment: Ok, so this mostly worked. Blog listing and individual blog pages are correct. The portfolio listing page and individual pages do not have the /blog/ which is correct. The remaining problem is this:  
  
When I go to my portfolio listing page, then click on one of the item's title-- to go to that item's page, it tries to go to example.com/blog/portfolio/porfolio-item-title   

Instead of going to the correct url of example.com/portfolio/portfolio-item-title

Comment: Did you register your post type correctly as described in my answer ? You should also flush Wordpress rewrite rules.

Comment: Yes, I had registered the post type how you described it.  I just now flushed the rewrite rules.  All of the blog pages are fine, but the portfolio is once again going to /blog/

Comment: Ah, that totally fixed it.  My bad.  Thank you so much!

Comment: This works, but my `/author/name/` pages are only available as `/blog/author/name/` now.. How can I fix this?

Comment: @soju – you're a life saver man... this is too obvious yet not so obvious.