# Showing the word "blog" in breadcrumbs in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and i am having issues displaying the breadcrumbs correctly when it comes to the blog section of my site.

The breadcrumbs display as home-->category-->post title,

Whereas i want it to display as home-->blog-->category-->post title.

How can i get this done.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom permalink plugin, give custom url to each post/page

http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

or review this thread
[Wordpress Custom Permalink for Just Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617820/wordpress-custom-permalink-for-just-posts)