# Custom Url structure for blog posts not for members and portfolios

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite

If I change permalinks settings then all post types use that structure.
For example:

```
https://www.domain.dom/blog/%category%/%postname%/
```

then portolio item resolve as

```
https://www.domain.dom/blog/portfolio/item/
```

And I want to remove /blog/ from url when displaying members portfolios, faq, etc.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617820/wordpress-custom-permalink-for-just-posts/15619416#15619416), but don't know do I need to register new post type, put that in theme functions.php or what to do with that?

Really need some guide on how to achive that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than you think, add a single php file to the wp-content/plugins directory, add a [plugin header comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/header-requirements/), then one call to [register_post_type()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/), e.g.:

```
<?php
/**
Plugin Name: My custom profiles
...
*/
add_action('init', function() {
    register_post_type('my_custom_profile', [
        'label' => 'Profiles',
        ...
    ]);
});
```