# How to add blog permalink on post?

Tags: wordpress, blogs, permalinks

i am running a website with sales theme in Wordpress

Since running webpage, i did not post blog at all.

But from the beginning, posting a blog post gets me an minor problem.

My url would like be like www.mywebpage/blog/ for blog post.

But if i change (added 'blog') permalink in custom like

/blog/%category%/%postname%/

it shows every single page with 'blog' even in my product.

In wordpress post, there are only blog posts ,around 4-5post, not the other.

For product posts are under theme' page and post and its more than 100..

i input 'blog' in 'category base' of permalink, nothing changed.

Is there any possible way to put 'blog' prefix for blog post?

Waiting for your kind help.

Comment: Duplicate post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617820/wordpress-custom-permalink-for-just-posts

Comment: i previously checked duplicate post, i cannot get it exactly, and where to put these code in which file.