# Wordpress - rewrite rule for posts only

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I wish I could modify the rewriting rule for posts/articles only.
I think there is solution whit **rewrite rules array** but I was not able to figure it out.

Maybe someone can help?

Best

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617820/wordpress-custom-permalink-for-just-posts

Comment: Thank you,
I have set the with_front of my custom post type to false, it works!