# Wordpress permalinks issue with blog posts & portfolios

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, permalinks

I'm using a Wordpress theme that contains portfolio posts. Currently, what I would normally consider to be 'pages' are actually 'portfolio' posts.

The site is using the 'Post Name' permalink structure, e.g.

> **domain.com/sample-post/**

This means blog posts are shown as:

> **domain.com/post-name**

while portfolio pages are displayed as

> **domain.com/portfolio/portfolio-name**

I actually want blog posts to be listed in a subfolder like this:

> **domain.com/blog/post-name**

Short of creating page templates and migrating the portfolio content onto pages, the only alternative I have found is to use the following custom permalink structure:

> **/%category%/%postname%/**

This fixes the 'visual' challenge, but this also means that I cannot use informative categories for those posts.

Am I overlooking a more simple solution? Please help!

P.s. Kudos to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874482/different-permalink-structure-for-blog-posts-than-pages-in-wordpress) for getting me to this point. I have tried to do some research, but haven't had much luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

The theme name would help clarify how the permalinks were defined for the custom post type 'Portfolio'.

However, with your current permalink structure, you can create a top-level category called 'blog' and move all your posts to it. (Migration is easy from the admin side using the bulk-edit facility). You can create informative categories as sub-categories of blog. Your blog posts will then be listed in the desired sub-folder (domain.com/blog/post-name) and portfolio should remain unchanged* (domain.com/portfolio/portfolio-name)
*This depends on how the permalinks were set up for the portfolio custom post type